# AngularJS. Memory leak. Object of this type is not attached to the DOM

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, memory-leaks

Memory does not decrease in IE especially. After taking a heap snapshot the main issue is HTMLDivElement "Object of this type is not attached to the DOM.". Count of the objects only increases.
Anything would help.
Thanks!

[heap snapshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTr0P.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an angular problem. My guess is more where you placed the div element in your html file. 
For example: What are the parents or children of this div element?

To my knowledge, every tag should be included in the DOM if the html file is written correctly.